# Android app widget with AdapterViewFlipper clear state

Tags: android, android-appwidget, remoteview

I'm developing app widget using AdapterViewFlipper and I have custom datasource with some elements.
 The problem is that when datasource changes the position remains the same. I need reset position when it happens, something like `setPosition(0)`, but RemoteView does not conteins this method.
I've tried to use `notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged` and reuse   `remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.page_flipper, intent);`
but it did not help.

Is there a better way than this ?

```
private resetPosition(int currentPage){
   for(int i=currentPage; i>0; i--){
       rv.showPrevious(R.id.page_flipper);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution!

```
rv.setDisplayedChild(R.id.page_flipper, 0);
```